# Jsoup element.class.class selcet method returning null

Tags: java, null, css-selectors, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to get to a `<button>` element inside a `<form>` element.

```
<form action="search.php" method="post" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="value"><span class="text-uppercase">Lyrics Search:</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="value" class="form-control input-sm">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="field" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="artist" >Artist</option>
                    <option value="title" >Title</option>
                    <option value="body"  >Body</option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Now the `<button>` element is inside 2 `HTML` classes and i know i need to concatenate those classes in the `select()` method.
Somehow my code returns `null` after the `select()` method.

**MyCode:**

```
HtmlPage htmlPage = new HtmlPage(Jsoup.connect("http://www.lyricsplanet.com/").get());

            // Get to <div class="form-group">
            Element searchFormElement = htmlPage.getHtmlDocument().select("div.form-group").first();
searchFormElement.attr("name", searchedLyrics); // Setting the value of name to the searched lyrics.

            // Getting to <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
            Element buttonElement = htmlPage.getHtmlDocument().select("button.btn btn-primary btn-sm.form-inline").first();
            System.out.println(buttonElement.html());
```

In - `select("button.btn btn-primary btn-sm.form-inline").first();` I try to get to the `<button>` element using It's two classes.

So what am i doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I just noticed there's 3! classes to the `<button>` element. That's more messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of a class called HtmlPage in Jsoup. You should use the Document-class which will be returned if you call Jsoup.connect(...);

You could try the following code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.lyricsplanet.com/").get(); // Just connect
Element formElement = document.select("div#alphabet > form").first(); // Search for form
formElement.select("input[name=value]").val(yourSearchValue); // Set your search value
Element submitButton = formElement.select("button[type=submit]").first(); // Then search in form for submit button, otherwise your selector could find another submit button first
```

The HTML Form elements (search-field and submit-button) do not have an identifier you could use. The only way is to use these specific css selectors.

Edit:
Do you want to submit the form afterwards? Then you don't have to search for the submit button. You can just submit the form after you've set the search value. Try the following code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.lyricsplanet.com/").get();
FormElement formElement = document.select("div#alphabet > form").forms().get(0); // Use FormElement instead of Element
formElement.select("input[name=value]").val(yourSearchValue);
Document searchResult = formElement.submit().post(); // Do anything you want with the search result page/html
```

Comment: `HtmlPage` is a class i have built. It's just connecting , nothing fancy. So the code you posted is to get to the search putting there my string value?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You're able to submit a form directly without searching for the submit button :) 
And yes, this code will set your search value into the form.

Comment: Thanks man. You can tell me how do i trigger the button click and get the `HTML` page acquired?

Comment: Why do you want to trigger the button click? With
    formElement.submit().post();
the form will be submitted and you get the Document containing the search results.

Comment: In your answer you said the `<form>` and `<button>` does not have and identifier to use. Is the `class` attribute not regarded as an identifier?!

Comment: Well, you could use the `class` attribute as identifier. But it could be, that there are multiple elements on a page with these classes. So you can't really be sure, that you selected the correct button. I prefer `id` and `name` attributes instead of using `class`-selectors. If an element doesn't have any `id` or `name` I prefer using specific selectors, such as `div#alphabet > form`. Then you can be sure, that you selected the correct element.

Comment: Great. Appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

To search with multiple classes for one element, you have to group multiple selectors like this `select("button.btn, button.btn-primary, button.btn-sm")`.

For details see http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax in the section *Selector combinations*.

Comment: So i changed the code to `Element buttonElement = htmlPage.getHtmlDocument().select("button.btn btn-primary btn-sm,"
     + "button.form-inline,button.form-group").first();` and It's still returning `null`.

Comment: You will have to remove that part `"button.btn btn-primary btn-sm,"`. The mentioned `select("button.btn, button.btn-primary, button.btn-sm")` will search for a `button` that has all three classes `btn`, `btn-primary`, and `btn-sm` assigned to it.

Comment: Let me get this strait. the `class="btn btn-primary btn-sm` is actually 3 classes which are `btn` , `btn-primary` and `btn-sm?! It's not just 1 class name?

Comment: Yep, three separate classes assigned to one button. That's why you need to group using the colon. This evaluates to something like *every button that has the class btn, btn-primary and btn-sm assigned*